# Two models ( with similar hyperparameters) loaded from same checkpoint giving different training results in PYTORCH

Tags: pytorch, checkpoint

I trained a model (Lenet-5) for 10 epochs and saved the model.
loaded into 2 models ‘new_model’, ‘new_model2’
below is the colab link
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1qQhyTWNzCgMYn8t0ZtIZilLgk4JptbJG?usp=sharing

trained the new models for 5 epochs, but ended up with different train and test accuracies for each epoch, in spite of loading from same model and setting reproducibility settings.

When I continue training the original model for 5 more epochs, the results are also different from the training results of 2 new models.

Is it possible that the test and train accuracies of original model (15 epochs), 2 new models (5 epochs after loading from the checkpoint) will be same?

(After loaded checkpoint I'm getting same test accuracy for all 3 models, but results are deviating on further training of each of models.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should reset all the seeds to a fixed value **right before** launching your experiments **every time** you launch an experiment. In short, this should be the order:

1. Set Seed
2. Train new model #1
3. Set Seed (again) to the same value.
4. Train new model #2

Reusing some of your code, we could define a function to set the seed, that should be called with the same value in steps 1 and 3:

```py
def set_seed(s):
   th.manual_seed(s)
   th.cuda.manual_seed_all(s)
   th.backends.cudnn.deterministic = True
   th.backends.cudnn.benchmark = False
   np.random.seed(s)
   random.seed(s)
   os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = str(s)
```

Comment: IT worked. Thank you so much @ibarrond . Now the 2 new models loaded from same checkpoint are giving similar train and test accuracies. Is there any way to match these new models' 'Test and Train accuracies' (say for 5 epochs) with the old (or original model) 'Test and Train accuracies' on continuing its old model's training (say for 5 more epochs)????   (as the new models and old model are now starting from similar weight settings)

Comment: I'm afraid it is not possible. You need the same setup (seed and weight initialization) to reproduce the same results. Since the initialization of the original model has different weights from those in the checkpoint, you just cannot align these two scenarios. Another question would be, why do you need this?

Comment: Thank you @ibarrond. Yes I think it is not possible though I use same seed function even at the beginning of the old model training I'm unable to get the similar results as new models. But when use this seed function again  just before training in old model too, for the second time (i.e after saving checkpoint) all the models' 'Test and Train accuracies are the same.

Comment: My main purpose is actually removing few filters from convolutional layers. I have 2 options for that creating new model with less filters and copying only the required things like weights of only few filters, optimizer etc. Other is modifying original network itself by removing all unnecessary weights,etc. So I just want to check if both are equal. _To my surprise in the colab link above (after 10 epochs of old models and 5 epochs of new models) Old model's test accuracy is always slightly higher (set_seed func used only once in old model)._